# VueJS v-if for disable / enable buttons

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My use case is something like this.

1. I have a html `<p>` element which's id is "demo".
2. I want to read that `<p>` element through `v-if` and if the value inside that

   element equals to the "**EXPIRED**" then I want to remove the `disabled` attribute in my button.

Future explaining my use case, I want to initially disabled my button and when the status updated to **EXPIRED** in that paragraph I want remove that disabled part from my button.

How to I achieve this using

1. computed properties / watchers
2. v-if

```js
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Start</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are setting this **EXPIRED** stuff using non-Vue *DOM manipulation* you are lost. Don't mix that with Vue. Instead I would do this:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
    <p id="demo">{{ status }}</p>
    <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="status !== 'EXPIRED'">Start</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

`status` being a property of your VM in the `data()` function.